# Binance Paper Trading Api?

Tags: python, api, trading, crypto++, binance

Can anyone recommend a Binance that has an API and supports Paper trading? I am currently experimenting with Binance webhooks and would like to test some strategies without risking real money. Binance unfortunately does not support paper trading...

Answer (score 7):

Yes, but you have to sign up with a GitHub account. Also, even if you already have a regular Binance account, you still have to sign up. The paper trading site is here:

https://testnet.binance.vision/

Also note that your account is provided with a balance of coins to trade:

> All users registering on the Spot Test Network automatically receive a balance in many different assets. Please note that these are not real assets and can be used only on the Spot Test Network itself.
>
> All funds on the Spot Test Network are virtual, and can not be transferred in/out of the Spot Test Network.

Comment: Is there a testing API for futures?

Comment: @AdamMendoza There is https://testnet.binancefuture.com/en/futures/BTCUSDT

Comment: Looks like it doesn't offer API though. What I'm trying to do is connect it to cornix to validate VIP signals before using real money

Comment: They have an api, after you login here https://testnet.binancefuture.com/en/futures/BTCUSDT, in the bottom section there's a tab "Api Key"